# How to limit frequency range using scipy FFT

Tags: python, scipy, signals, signal-processing, fft

I am using FFT do find the frequencies of a signal. I am only interested in a certain range of frequencies, between 1 and 4 Hz.

I have this code to compute frequencies:

```
from scipy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq, irfft

plt.plot(d)
plt.show()
N = len(d)
yf = rfft(d)
xf = rfftfreq(N, 1 / sample_rate) # 29
plt.plot(xf, np.abs(yf))
plt.show()
```

Which results in :

[image]

How do I modify my code so that `xf` and `yf` only correspond to frequencies in my desired range of 1-4 Hz, instead of the 0-15 seen in the plot?

Comment: so do you want to reduce the xaxis to 1-4 in the lower plot, is that right ?

Comment: @JayPatel yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xlim` feature of `matplotlib` to modify `x axis`.

Here is the example code that you can refer.

```py
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
import numpy as np
# Number of sample points
N = 600
# sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 800.0
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N, endpoint=False)
y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
yf = fft(y)
xf = fftfreq(N, T)[:N//2]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2]),'b')
plt.plot()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2]),'b')
plt.xlim(0,100) # you need this
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, right. I was making it more complicated in my head. How do I edit the actual `xf` and `yf` arrays with this filter so that I could plot the same results without needed xlim?

Comment: @connor449 What do you mean by filter ? I don't see any filter in the code. And why do you not want to use `xlim`, can you please explain a bit ?

Comment: I have your `xlim` implementation working to visualize the frequencies I am interested in. However, I want to do operations on the in-range frequencies, like find the 1st and 2nd most powerful frequencies. To do so, I need the out of range frequencies removed from the array so I can do things like `np.max()`

Comment: do you want to find a fft peak ?